# does react prevent re-render unless event handler finishes executing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, single-page-application

[image]

I'm using react-redux and setCurrentPage is a method that is imported using mapDispatchToProps. What I don't understand is that if redux is synchronous and I change something inside state using setCurrentPage when calling onPageChanged event handler then why don't I get the changed props when using axios ? I'm thinking that maybe the case is that props are updated immutably and we cannot use different props inside one render cycle, but if that's the case doesn't setCurrentPage trigger re-render? or maybe react somehow blocks the re-rendering process unless the onPageChanged event handler finishes executing. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It will re-render only if you have a prop linked from the redux state to your component via a selector. please post full code snippets of the connect redux hoc and avoid posting code in images.

Comment: Redux state is not component state. Components re-render on its own state changes.

Comment: Every time the store gets updated, your component connected with redux, gets re-rendered.